# Does EL Expression evaluation depend upon jsp version or Servlet Container version?

Tags: jsp, servlets, el, jsp-tags

Does **EL Expression evaluation** depend upon **jsp version** too? Or is it that it only depends upon **Servlet Container version**?

> My servlet version is 3.0 and JSP version is 2.1

After googling a bit, I found out that my JSP should evaluate EL Expressions efficiently because

> Servlet Container version 2.4 or higher has EL Expressions enabled by default

But it doesn't work and I have to explicitly declare **isELIgnored="false"** and only then it works correctly.

Please tell me whether **JSP version** also impacts **EL Expression Evaluation**

Comment: What is your servlet container? This might be a particular bug (or feature, ehm) of your servlet container.

Comment: Sir, My Servlet Container is Tomcat 7

Comment: Then you are probably hitting a similar bug as discussed in http://osdir.com/ml/users-tomcat.apache.org/2014-11/msg00136.html / regrattably, I don't know the solution.